# How to force SQL to use linked server not the original sever

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

I have added a linked server 'LinkedServer2' (which is linked to 'OriginalServer2') to my LocalServer. Sometimes I have an issue that it either sees only my LocalServer or the OriginalServer2. And it is a fiasco because I cannot join to tables.

How to run code forcing it to start from my LocalServer and then join table from LinkedServer2 (not OriginalServer2).

Sometimes restarting SQL Management Studio helps adding to the mystery. I use SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: Please, do also tag SQL SERVER.

Comment: This is confusing.  Can you please reword it?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% on question but you can query linked servers using [server].[database].[schema].[table]

Comment: But how do I know which server do I query? Both of them, the linked, and the original, have got the same names.